# why php accessing variables defined in other pages?

Tags: php, session, variables

This is strange, I don't know how its possible, my coliuge working on a small project here is the code

```
<?php
include 'database/dbconnect.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
   header('location:index.php');
}
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid));
print_r($user);
?>
```

and its getting result..

the variable `$fbid` is not `defined` in this page, but in another page for some different purpose.
but `php` not showing any `error`, giving the result. i cleared `sessions` and `cookies` nothing happened.

#### the dbconnect.php

```
session_start();
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="uuuu";
$dbpass="pppp";
$dbdatabase="dddd";

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);

mysql_select_db($dbdatabase) or die("Connection Failed");
```

#### the other page where $fbid is defined

```
include 'dbconnect.php';
if (isset($_POST['me'])) {
    $me = $_POST['me'];
    $fbid = $me['id'];
    $name = $me['name'];
}
```

and clearly these ^ two pages has no connection, no `include` no `require`. and both are in different folders

Comment: Other page you mean `dbconnect.php` ?

Comment: by other page you mean which page ? where $fbid is exactly defined .. you are saying you cleared your session in case you did then this page should redirect to index.php further code isn't suppose to run ..

Comment: nope... in that page there is only database connection.. nothing else, I've checked that too

Comment: You are getting *a* result. Are you getting *the* result for some user with a specific `$fbid`? Have you tried `var_dump($fbid)`?

Comment: and what do you call "it's getting result" ? if $fbid is empty, a json object is returned with an "error" property.

Comment: @SyedQarib, yes its redirecting, in index page it will ask for login, after login in the login page the `variable` is used. after successful login it will redirect to welcome page where this code is written  thing happening...

Comment: add the full code from `database/dbconnect.php` (don't forget to hide the dbname/username/passwd infos)

Comment: @Asenar: result means response from facebook, the reason i asked this question is , i did not understand whats happening here, that $fb id is not empty it says, i tried `echo $fbid`. its working fine, hows that possible..

Comment: Ok, so the answer is "fbid is defined somewhere". If not in database.php, it's in a file included inside that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try make

```
print_r($GLOBALS)
```

And try find in output fbid variable

Comment: +1 yes bro, thank it worked. but i didn't get how its works, we have not `defined` it as `global` `variable`, now how to `unset`??

Answer (score 1):

To display errors, you need to add the following at the beginning of your script :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: nice try, but we are not using `error_report(0);`. its showing if there any other `errors` in the page.

Comment: by default error_report is usually set to hide E_NOTICE (and sometimes E_WARNING) errors. by setting to E_ALL, you force it to take all errors

Answer (score 0):

On Facebook, an identifier (FBID) is assigned to most pieces of content. You can use the FBID to cite a piece of content precisely and concisely using the URL. Hence it is possible to get the value of $fbid in the other page. If you try doing this outside Facebook, you can get the error

Answer (score 0):

> You should start session

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include 'database/dbconnect.php';
  if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  header('location:index.php');
  }
  $user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid));
   print_r($user);
  ?>
```